# Symfony - Key "skills" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

i'm trying to display all related properties of my Jointure Entity in twig.

Here are my 3 entities :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\JointureRepository")
 */
class Jointure
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="jointure")
     */
    private $skills;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="jointure")
     */
    private $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->skills = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Skill[]
     */
    public function getSkills(): Collection
    {
        return $this->skills;
    }

    public function addSkill(Skill $skill): self
    {
        if (!$this->skills->contains($skill)) {
            $this->skills[] = $skill;
            $skill->setJointure($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSkill(Skill $skill): self
    {
        if ($this->skills->contains($skill)) {
            $this->skills->removeElement($skill);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($skill->getJointure() === $this) {
                $skill->setJointure(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Answer[]
     */
    public function getAnswers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    public function addAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if (!$this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers[] = $answer;
            $answer->setJointure($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if ($this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($answer->getJointure() === $this) {
                $answer->setJointure(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Skill entity with ManyToOne => Jointure relation :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SkillRepository")
 */
class Skill
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Jointure", inversedBy="skills")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $jointure;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setLabel(string $label): self
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJointure(): ?Jointure
    {
        return $this->jointure;
    }

    public function setJointure(?Jointure $jointure): self
    {
        $this->jointure = $jointure;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My entity Answer is the same that Skill with UserEmail property.

So in my controller :

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @var JointureRepository
     */

    public function __construct(JointureRepository $repository, ObjectManager $em)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $JointureRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Jointure::class);
        $jointure = $JointureRepository->findAll();

        foreach($jointure as $jointures){
            $skills = $jointures->getSkills();
            $answers = $jointures->getAnswers();
        }
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
            'jointure' => $jointure,
            'skills' => $skills,
            'answers' => $answers,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to display them in twig :

```
{% for jointures in jointure.skills %}   
   {{jointures.label}}   
{% endfor %}
```

I've the following error : **Key "skills" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.**
At line : {% for jointures in jointure.skills %}

If i do :

```
{% for skill in skills %}
{{skill.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

3,4 appears but not the 1,2 related to Jointure with id = 0 ..
Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you dump out the output of this line?

```
$jointure = $JointureRepository->findAll();
```

If you did, you should have seen that `$jointure` is not a single object of that class but an array.

You even used it as an array in your Controller code:

```
foreach($jointure as $jointures){
    $skills = $jointures->getSkills();
    $answers = $jointures->getAnswers();
}
```

You're using the array as it would be a single object in twig, that's your issue. You need to either go trough the array, to get the skills, or you need to receive a single jointure to use it as you'd like to.

```
{% for object in jointure %}
    {% for jointures in object.skills %}   
        {{jointures.label}}   
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As a basic note, take a look at your naming of variables. Those are misleading and are not representing the value that it contains.

```
$arrJointures = $JointureRepository->findAll();
```

`$arrJointures` would be a suitable variable, since this contains an array of jointures. Also, with this naming, you should see that this code couln't be working.

```
{% for jointures in arrJointures.skills %}   
   {{jointures.label}}   
{% endfor %}
```